# Laravel get all conversations with participants current user participates in

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have four tables. `User, Conversations, Message and Conversation_Participants`. [image: I hope you don't find a relationship error in this image]
(I hope you don't find a relationship error in this image )

I tried to add a function

```
public function conversations(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Conversation::class, 'conversation_participants', 'user_id', 'conversation_id');
}
```

to `User::class` but if i call `User::with('conversations')->get()` i only get all existing Users. What am I doing wrong? First i want to get all conversations the current user participates in and second I want to get all receivers of the conversations.

I also tried

```
public function participants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'conversation_participants', 'user_id', 'conversation_id');
}
```

in the `Conversation::class` but `Conversation::with('participants')->get()` gets me all Conversation even those the user isn't participating in.

I'm really confused atm :/

Comment: Please try to change your `partiancipants()` `return $this->belongsToMany(App\User, 'conversation_participants', 'conversation_id', 'user_id');`. And try in your controller `User::with('participants')->get();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following in your `User` model:

```
public function conversations() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Conversation::class, 'conversation_participants', 'users_id', 'conversations_id');
}
```

And this to your `Conversation` model:

```
public function participants() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'conversation_participants', 'conversation_id', 'users_id');
}
```

If you want to link your tables easier, [read up on conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

To get all the conversations a user is participating in, run the following (assuming you've loaded the user): `$user->conversations()` to get all the conversations a user is in.

If you want all users, with all their conversations, with all the participants connected, do the following: `$users = Users::with('conversations.participants')->get()`. You can now loop through this as follows:

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    foreach($user->conversations as $conversation) { 
        foreach($conversations->participants as $participant) {
            // do fancy stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the user from which you start is also a participant, so maybe you need to filter that one out again.

If you want to get even more fancy (but use more resources) you could even query all the messages a conversation has too!

```
User::with('conversations.participants', 'conversations.messages.user')->get()
```

But this only works when you set up a second set of relationships along the upper table in your image `(conversations <-> messages <-> users)`

**Edit**

In the comments, OP asked if it was possible to limit the amount of messages retrieved from the database, which is possible to my knowledge, but I don't now if this is the best way:

Remove the messages from the first eager loading part:

```
User::with('conversations.participants')
```

After that, when looping through the conversations, lazy load the messages:

```
$conversation->load(['messages' => function($query){
    $query->take(5);
}, 'users']);
```

Access them after that with $conversation->messages.

**Note**

*I think this could be done more easily in one go, but I don't have a setup right now to test this for you.*

**Edit 2**

After Ronon added another comment, here's what I came up with:

Add a new relationship in the `Conversation` model:

```
public function last_messages() {
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'conversation_id', 'id')->latest()->limit(2);
}
```

Because of that, you now can do this:

```
User::with('conversations.participants', 'conversations.last_messages.users')->get()
```

If you still want all the messages, you can use the `messages` relationship. If you want less, use the `last_messages` one.

Comment: Wow, thank you. The part with the messages would have followed in one of the next steps. But is there a way to limit the messages loaded? For example load only the last 5 messages? Messages has the `$table->timestamps()` attr as well, so ordering isn't a problem.

Comment: @Ronon It's up there now

Comment: Thanks :) I maybe found a [better?] solution. In Conversation -> messages function i just added `hasMany(Message::class)->latest()->limit(2)` . Seems to work as wished. Don't know if it's good or bad. Would appreciate some response to this, even my main problem was already solved.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `User::with('conversations')->get()` does not specify a User. I might be misreading but I think you are looking for something like the following:

```
$user = User::with('conversations')->find(1);
$userConversations = $user->conversations;
```

which will provide you with a user and their conversations.

Comment: The parenthesis on the last line aren't needed, that would only bring you back in query mode. For the rest, spot on!